# How to fix app crash on recieving FCM Push Notification built on Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I have built an app on Flutter and was trying to send Push Notifications through FCM. Earlier it was working but after changing the version of Firebase messaging the app crashes as soon as I send a push notification.

I haven't made any changes in the Code per se. I looked into the GitHub issues but couldn't resolve it.

This is the code I have been using in the main.dart file.

```
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('on message $message');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      print(token);
    });
```

My firebase_messaging dependency

```
  firebase_messaging: ^1.0.2
```

I had also changed the version of google-services in app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
```

This is the part added to the AndroidManifest.xml file for notifications

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

The Device Log

`03-24 19:14:25.044  2630  2663 I ActivityManager: Start proc 17709:com.example.notif_app/u0a206 for broadcast com.example.notif_app/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver
03-24 19:14:25.047 17709 17709 I art     : Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-24 19:14:25.181 17709 17709 D FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
03-24 19:14:25.182 17709 17709 D FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
03-24 19:14:25.182 17709 17709 I FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
03-24 19:14:25.199 17709 17730 I ResourceExtractor: Found extracted resources res_timestamp-1-1553431828587
03-24 19:14:25.206 17709 17727 I FA      : App measurement is starting up, version: 15300
03-24 19:14:25.206 17709 17727 I FA      : To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-24 19:14:25.207 17709 17727 I FA      : To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
03-24 19:14:25.207 17709 17727 I FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.notif_app
03-24 19:14:25.220 17709 17709 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-24 19:14:25.221 17709 17709 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 19:14:25.221 17709 17709 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.notif_app, PID: 17709
03-24 19:14:25.221 17709 17709 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzad()Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzan; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzan; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzan' appears in /data/app/com.example.notif_app-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
03-24 19:14:25.221 17709 17709 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzb(Unknown Source)
03-24 19:14:25.221 17709 17709 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
03-24 19:14:25.221 17709 17709 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3318)
03-24 19:14:25.221 17709 17709 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)`

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the error output.

Comment: @Ryosuke when the app crashed there was no error log in the logcat neither in the run tab. Any other way to check the error log

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: open the android folder inside Android Studio. There in the logcat edit filter configuration and set you package name.

Comment: I used adb logcat to check the device log and extracted the required ones needed concerning my app. I have edited the question with the same.

Comment: did you try this version `^4.0.0+1` of firebase messaging? because this error usually means firebase dependency version mismatch.

Comment: I added ``` implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3' ``` in the app/build.gradle and now it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the android project.

Go the build.gradle of firebase_messaging

In the dependencies change `api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'` to 
        `api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'`

Make sure you are using the latest version of all the cloud dependencies in pubspec.yaml

This solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Just run `flutter clean` and run your app again.

Comment: It worked,but also i had to clean the app's storgae,better is uninstalling and reinstalling the app,

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed the plugin instructions https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging
but still, my Android app crashed.

The reason was in file `android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/app/MainActivity.kt`

When I changed it to

```
package YOUR.APP.PACKAGE

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

The crash has gone.

Also just in case, the code to listen for coming pushes, there is important to have the handler for `onBackgroundMessage`

```
static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async { print(message); return Future<void>.value(); }

firebaseMessaging.configure(
      // when app is open
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        try {
          Get.defaultDialog(
              title: message['notification']['title'] ?? 'New reaction to comment',
              middleText: message['notification']['body'] ?? 'Click to react',
              textCancel: 'Cancel',
              textConfirm: 'See',
              onCancel: () {},
              onConfirm: () => PushServices.managePushesLinkToProject(message));
        } catch (e) {
          print('$e');
        }
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        PushServices.managePushesLinkToProject(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        PushServices.managePushesLinkToProject(message);
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
    );
```

The key solution was found here https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2311